# How to make TFrame with rounded corners?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, frame, delphi-2006

I want to make a component based on a `TFrame` with `TLMDShapeControl` (for drawing round corner background) and a `TEdit` control (that can be also a `TComboBox` or a `TDBEdit` and so on).
After that I will use the "Add to Palette" command to turn it into a Reusable Component Control.

The problem in that I need it to be width flexible and for that I had the idea of turn everything inside the Frame `alClient` and the `TEdit` with 5 pixel margin so the user can see the rounded corners.

It was terrible because I can't use `Align` and set components one in the top of another. Now I have to copy and paste the components on every time I have to use it! :-(((

The only way I see the right thing is to use only the `TEdit` with `alClient` and 5px margin and no `TShape`. Instead I could make the `TFrame` to be rounded corner with transparency, so it won't look ugly on of different colors or `TImages`.

But how do I do that?

Does anyone have any code sample?

[image: this is the goal: transparent rounded corners]

Comment: If I wanted this to work properly, I'd make my own control that I install as a package, that contains the outer and inner control, and contains all the code that I want to make it all work.  `TFrame` is not the correct parent class. I would use a plain `TCustomControl`.  Frames are for composition of visual controls at design-time rather than at compile time.  But compiling your own custom control is the more reliable and resilient solution.

Comment: I have done exactly that, using the built in TShape instead of `TLMDShapeControl` and it worked fine. But in the end, I abandoned these styles, because my customers hate these non-native styles and wanted them gone.

Comment: Yes, `TShape` can be rounded corner, but the output is very buggy. I don't have a crew, so I am the one who investigate requirements, make the project, the code and the design of the system and the database of my projects and I did not had the possibility to become an expert at one of these things... yet! :-)

Comment: The same is with using `CreateRoundRectRgn`. GDI just doesn't support any kind of antialiasing, thus you don't get smooth corners. If I were you, I would use a `TCustomControl` like Warren suggested, e.g. [`this way`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11252604/960757). Then there are *just* two problems, one is the transparency of such control and the second one is the need of a library that can render smooth arc for your corners.

Comment: The worse is that you can't set the percentage of the roundness... So if you create a big control, you get a big corner.

Comment: You meant `TShape` in your last comment. But anyway would it be enough for you to have a *shape* under your components or you need a container ?

Comment: That is how I am doing it now. But not very nice, right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To answer your question how to make frame with rounded corners you can try something like this, but you will be dissatisfied with the result since the [`CreateRoundRectRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) used here has no antialiasing.

```
type
  TFrame1 = class(TFrame)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
  protected
    procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TFrame1.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
var
  Region: HRGN;
begin
  inherited;
  Region := CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight, 30, 30);
  SetWindowRgn(Handle, Region, True);
end;
```

***Update:***

Since GDI doesn't have any function that would support antialiasing for arc rendering, I've posted here an example of a round rectangle shape (just a pure filled round rectangle) that uses GDI+ (for this you will need GDI+ wrappers [`from here`](http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/GdiPlus1.2.zip)).

The following properties are important for its use:

- Color - is the shape fill color (can be enhanced of pen color, gradient etc.)
- Radius - is the radius (in pixels) of the circle used to draw the rounded corners
- AlphaValue - is the opacity value of the rendered round rectangle (just for fun :-)

```
unit RoundShape;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Controls, Graphics, GdiPlus;

type
  TCustomRoundShape = class(TGraphicControl)
  private
    FRadius: Integer;
    FAlphaValue: Integer;
    procedure SetRadius(Value: Integer);
    procedure SetAlphaValue(Value: Integer);
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    property Radius: Integer read FRadius write SetRadius default 10;
    property AlphaValue: Integer read FAlphaValue write SetAlphaValue default 255;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TRoundShape = class(TCustomRoundShape)
  public
    property Canvas;
  published
    property Align;
    property AlphaValue;
    property Anchors;
    property Color;
    property Constraints;
    property DragCursor;
    property DragKind;
    property DragMode;
    property Enabled;
    property Font;
    property ParentColor;
    property ParentFont;
    property ParentShowHint;
    property PopupMenu;
    property Radius;
    property ShowHint;
    property Visible;
    property OnClick;
    property OnContextPopup;
    property OnDblClick;
    property OnDragDrop;
    property OnDragOver;
    property OnEndDock;
    property OnEndDrag;
    property OnMouseActivate;
    property OnMouseDown;
    property OnMouseEnter;
    property OnMouseLeave;
    property OnMouseMove;
    property OnMouseUp;
    property OnStartDock;
    property OnStartDrag;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

{ TCustomRoundShape }

constructor TCustomRoundShape.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Width := 213;
  Height := 104;
  FRadius := 10;
  FAlphaValue := 255;
end;

procedure TCustomRoundShape.SetRadius(Value: Integer);
begin
  if FRadius <> Value then
  begin
    FRadius := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TCustomRoundShape.SetAlphaValue(Value: Integer);
begin
  if FAlphaValue <> Value then
  begin
    FAlphaValue := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TCustomRoundShape.Paint;
var
  GPPen: TGPPen;
  GPColor: TGPColor;
  GPGraphics: IGPGraphics;
  GPSolidBrush: IGPSolidBrush;
  GPGraphicsPath: IGPGraphicsPath;
begin
  GPGraphicsPath := TGPGraphicsPath.Create;
  GPGraphicsPath.Reset;
  GPGraphicsPath.AddArc(0, 0, FRadius, FRadius, 180, 90);
  GPGraphicsPath.AddArc(ClientWidth - FRadius - 1, 0, FRadius, FRadius, 270, 90);
  GPGraphicsPath.AddArc(ClientWidth - FRadius - 1, ClientHeight - FRadius - 1,
    FRadius, FRadius, 0, 90);
  GPGraphicsPath.AddArc(0, ClientHeight - FRadius - 1, FRadius, FRadius, 90, 90);
  GPGraphicsPath.CloseFigure;

  GPColor.InitializeFromColorRef(ColorToRGB(Color));
  GPColor.Alpha := FAlphaValue;
  GPPen := TGPPen.Create(GPColor);
  GPSolidBrush := TGPSolidBrush.Create(GPColor);

  GPGraphics := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
  GPGraphics.SmoothingMode := SmoothingModeAntiAlias;
  GPGraphics.FillPath(GPSolidBrush, GPGraphicsPath);
  GPGraphics.DrawPath(GPPen, GPGraphicsPath);
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Stack Overflow', [TRoundShape]);
end;

end.
```

And the result (with [`SmoothingModeAntiAlias`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) smoothing mode applied):

[image]

One can say it's a big overhead to use GDI+ for such tiny thing but pure GDI render without antialiasing what makes the results looks ugly. Here is the example of the same round rectangle rendered by using pure GDI:

[image]

Comment: That answers my question. I will try to make a component in wich we could choose the kind of control we want above the rounded shape and see if it is better than the tframe way. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! But I have to warn you; if you'll follow the `TCustomControl` way like I mentioned in the comment above for instance, be careful with transparency. I've been trying to make the container control (like `TPanel` for instance is) transparent when Windows themes are disabled, but it never been satisfying.

Comment: How do we apply this new component to the rounded corner frame?

Comment: It's just a shape component with antialiased corners with what you can replace `TShape`. I've posted it here since you've discussed `TShape` in comments above. But frame can be transparent (`ParentBackground` set to True) thus it might be enough to place this shape under your controls.

Comment: If you go with the Region approach, don't forget to resize the Region every time the frame is resized. Creating a fixed-size region in `CreateWnd()` alone is not enough.